# WordPress: $wpdb query returning double

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been stuck on this for about an hour and my hair is turning grey.

For some reason when I try to run this query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_units WHERE user_id = $user->ID AND post_units = $id";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

foreach ($results as $result) {
  echo $result->post_units;

}
```

I get this output:

> 99 1212 1616 1919

In the database I have:

```
|id | user_id | post_units
 1      1        9
 2      1        12
 3      1        16
 4      1        19
```

Can anyone see why?

Edit:

$wpdb->last_query; also returns double the times.

> SELECT * FROM wp_units WHERE user_id = 1 AND post_units = 9 SELECT * FROM wp_units WHERE user_id = 1 AND post_units = 9

Comment: from this table data it looks it will return only one record. Did you checked it by printing query `$wpdb->last_query` ?

Comment: @milankyada see updated question

Comment: is this query in loop?

Comment: Nope, I thought $wpdb does not need to be in a loop?

Comment: It should not be in loop. I tried this same code and I am getting proper result that's why I asked you :)

Comment: oh hang on a sec. This code is in a function called checkProgress() which is called in the loop after each post is listed so I can display if the user has seen that post or not.

Comment: also the code did work correctly, until wordpress updated itself on my server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121456/discussion-between-milan-kyada-and-jamesg).